# SVM different results in R with same input and parameters

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, scalability

I have developed a SVM model for fraud detection in a train dataset using the following parameters:

```
set.seed(1234)
gamma.optimal <- 0.02
cost.optimal <- 4
svm_model1 <- svm(log(response+0.00012345) ~ . , data_test, kernel="radial", gamma=gamma.opt, cost=cost.opt)
```

After creating the SVM, I evaluated my svm_model1 in a test data set to obtain the total fraud quantity:
`sum(response)` and it was equal to 30.080 USD:

```
predictions <- exp(predict(svm_model1 , testing))
```

This result was equal in a laptop (local mode with R GUI) and a small cluster using SparkR (4 nodes and 1 master with Cloudera 5.6).

Happy with these results I tried to perform **the same R script** with **the same test data set**, **the same svm_model1** saved with `set.seed(1234)` in a .Rdata executable file, but this time in 2 different systems: Oracle BDA (6 slave nodes and 1 master) and another one with 4 slave nodes and Cloudera 5.7.

The results in these 2 final systems were: `sum(response)` equal to 30.130 USD, using the same.

```
predictions <- exp(predict(svm_model1 , testing))
```

My question is:

1) If I used the same script, the same model saved in an executable file (.Rdata), and the same data; how is it possible that `e1071` svm with a radial kernel gives me different results?

2) Are these results related with radial kernel nature's and parallel processing issues or different hardware characteristics? Or if you use `set.seed()` then no matter what hardware you have the result must be the same in R using `predict()` function?

I thank you very much in advance for your time and help. Best regards.

Comment: Questions about software are off topic here. We can try this on [SO]. You could also try the r-help listserv if you don't get a good answer there.

Comment: sounds to me like a rounding error or an error due to some approximation, either in the iterative solution in the svm or e.g. in the implmentation of the e.g. exp() function using taylor expansions or so

Comment: @gung Thanks for your reply. I will follow your advice and post this question in Stack Overflow. Regards.

Comment: @fcop Thanks for your reply. Do you think adding a `round(variable, 4)` could help in improving the results to be the same? Regards.

Comment: @GeneralAbrial thanks for your reply. It was in fact a small mistake while changing object names in order to make them more simple. I have already edited the question to be 100% understandable. Regards.

Comment: Don't you think it's worth trying? :-)

Comment: Please do not cross-post. That is against SE policy. If you can wait a minute, we will migrate this for you.

Comment: OK @gung, I will not cross-post this question (I did not know about this rule). How could I follow-up this question in Stack Overflow when it is migrated? Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Hi @fcop, yes. In fact I already have your advice as an alternative solution to solve this problem. Nevertheless, `round(variable, number_of_floating_points)` will make the predictions lose a little accuracy, that is why I would prefer another approximation to solve this in first place. Thanks for replying.

Comment: You already have an account on SO. You should get a notification in your inbox. When you navigate to this post, it will be there.

Comment: @fcop As replied to complexM, I added a 5 significative values rounding to the process in "prediction" and "exp" operation command lines. However, results maintained the difference in fraud prediction (30.130 USD in the first case and 30.080 USD in the second case with minimum decimals difference). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

as the prediction function is (obviously) deterministic, the results should be the same-- but e1071 uses LIBSVM, i.e. C++ code-- and floating point operations can (and will) vary between hardware platforms (and even for different compiler flags and/or compilers). 
you could try to write your own R prediction function, that should give (for fixed models) the very same answer on all platforms.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I added significative values rounding to the "prediction" command line and to the "exp" operation in order to set 5 significant values in the process. However, the results maintained the difference in fraud prediction (30.130 USD in the first case and 30.080 USD in the second case with minimum decimals difference).

Comment: i'm not quite sure how rounding relates to my answer. as said, the problem is within the C++ code, so if you have many many support vectors (=floating point operations) the differences might (or will) get larger and larger on different platforms, e.g. the difference might get 2 USD. so rounding is not really helping, as long as you do it from outside. if you do it 'inside' the prediction loop, it would help, because then the differences will be removed with each floating point operation. as said, if you must have 100% same results, a prediction routine entirly in R will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way you may check what is going on is to compute predicted values yourself (not using the predict function). Here is an illustration on how to manually compute predicted values for svm model objects created within e1071.

```
#TO GENERAGE TOY DATA
set.seed(994522)
Se <- 0.15
D <- data.frame(X=runif(n=20,min=0,max=6))
D$ActualY <- 3 + sin(D$X)
D <- D[order(D$X),]
rownames(D) <- 1:nrow(D)
D$Residual <- rnorm(n=nrow(D),mean=0,sd=Se)
NoisyPoints <- sample(1:nrow(D),8,replace=F)
D$Noise <- ifelse(rownames(D) %in% NoisyPoints,rnorm(n=nrow(D),mean=0,sd=2*Se),0)
D$Noisy <- ifelse(rownames(D) %in% NoisyPoints,1,0)
D$Y <- D$ActualY + D$Residual + D$Noise
D[,-5] <- round(D[,-5],digits=2)

#PARAMETER GRID
(MyEpsilons <- mean(D$Y)*c(0.01, seq(0.05, 0.20, 0.05)))
(MyGammas <- 10^(seq(-3, 3, 1)))
(MyCosts <- 10^(0:3))

#PARAMETER TUNING
TunesRBF <- tune.svm(x=D$X, y=D$Y, gamma=MyGammas, cost=MyCosts, epsilon=MyEpsilons, kernel="radial")
(BestPar <- summary(TunesRBF)$best.parameters)
(BestSVRrbf <- best.svm(x=D$X, y=D$Y,tunecontrol=tune.control(cross=5),cost=MyCosts,epsilon=MyEpsilons,gamma=MyGammas))

#SVM FITTING
(SVRrbf <- svm(x=D$X, y=D$Y, gamma=BestPar$gamma, cost=BestPar$cost, epsilon=BestPar$epsilon, kernel="radial"))

#TO GENERATE NEW SAMPLES
set.seed(224599)
NewSamples <- data.frame(X=runif(n=5,min=0,max=6))
NewSamples$PredY <- predict(SVRrbf,NewSamples)
NewSamples <- round(NewSamples,digits=2)

#TO EXTRACT MODEL PARAMETERS
V <- as.matrix(SVRrbf$SV)
A <- as.matrix(SVRrbf$coefs)
(g <- SVRrbf$gamma)
(C <- SVRrbf$cost)
(r <- SVRrbf$rho)

#TO MANUALLY GET PREDICTED VALUES NEW SAMPLES
X <- NewSamples[,1,drop=F]
KernelNewSamples <- matrix(0, nrow(NewSamples), nrow(V))
MeanX <- mean(D[,1])  #YOU NEED THIS FOR STANDARDIZING NEW SAMPLES
SdX <- sd(D[,1])  #YOU NEED THIS FOR STANDARDIZING NEW SAMPLES
#STANDARDIZATION
Xs <- (NewSamples[,1,drop=F]-MeanX)/SdX
#GETTING THE KERNEL FOR THE rbf
for (i in 1:nrow(NewSamples)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(V)) {
        Xi <- Xs[i,]
        Vj <- V[j,]
        XiMinusVj <- Xi - Vj
        SumSqXiMinusVj <- XiMinusVj %*% XiMinusVj
        KernelNewSamples[i,j] <- exp(-g*SumSqXiMinusVj)
    }
}

#TO PREDICT NEW SAMPLES
PredNewSamples <- KernelNewSamples %*% A - r
#TO BACK TRANSFORM TO ORIGINAL Y SCALE
MeanY <- as.numeric(SVRrbf$y.scale[1])
StdY <- as.numeric(SVRrbf$y.scale[2])
PredNewSamples <- PredNewSamples*StdY + rep(MeanY,nrow(NewSamples))
cbind(NewSamples,PredNewSamples)
```

Answer (score 0):

The svr package also suggests cross-validation which is default with k = 10 (k-fold cross validation) in the case of tune.svr

As the process of choosing the sets is quite random it can cause different results (but very similar) in each execution and consequently different prediction results in the case of SVM.

In Wikipedia about cross-validation we read:

> In k-fold cross-validation, the original sample is randomly
>   partitioned into k equal sized subsamples. Of the k subsamples, a
>   single subsample is retained as the validation data for testing the
>   model, and the remaining k − 1 subsamples are used as training data.
>   The cross-validation process is then repeated k times, with each of
>   the k subsamples used exactly once as the validation data. The k
>   results can then be averaged to produce a single estimation.